# PL/SQL Use Parameters Contains Quotation Marks

Tags: sql, plsql

I wrote a procedure that included parameters type varchar2 and i pass from my application string is like that "'O','H','Y'" and my query is below.

```
select * from table_name t where t.productname in (parameter)
```

Query does not return any data. How to handle it?

I try yo double or three quatitions marks.

Answer (score 2):

Try to set the parameter like this **'O,H,Y'**

[Here](http://www.williamrobertson.net/documents/comma-separated.html) you can see some examples

Comment: The reason this is a good answer is that special characters like apostrophes get escaped when strings are sent to databases as query parameters.  At some point, you are going to have to tell the database to treat the parameter as a list.  The details depend on the programming language you are using for your application.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to pass a procedure as parameter then you should get nothing or error. You can only pass a function that returns a value as we all know. You need to add your code and samples to help you more. What exactly are you passing in ()?

```
-- Correct syntax to pass parameters in your case --
select * from table_name t where t.productname in ('O', 'H', 'Y')
/
```

Answer (score 0):

To pass single quotes in an sql query, use single quotes twice. Simple!

You can have:

```
select * from table_name t where t.productname in ('''O''', '''H''', '''Y''')
```

To test this, you can use:

```
SELECT 'Schindler''s List' AS fname FROM dual;
```

and see that you can easily pass single quotes to a query.

Double quotes are not much of matter here. We can directly use double quotes inside an SQL string literal, like

```
SELECT 'He said, "Give me my teddy bear!"' AS dilogue FROM dual;
```